# How to use github actions workflow file for all branches?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I created a workflow file in master branch and all other release branches and test/devbranches branched out from master, got their own this workflow file and able to execute them.

But, if I want to change any data in the workflow like adding few steps, it seems need to update all the branch specific copies of this file.

Is there any way to keep only one copy of the workflow file and refer the same from other branches also?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot do that the way you want it.

Separate branches have their own workflow files, so after you change it on `master` you have to re-base all other branches to reflect those changes everywhere.

It has both pros and cons - sometimes it's actually important to test some workflow changes on branches before you merge them to master.